# I cannot write to stdin with /proc/{pid}/fd/0

Tags: c, bash, ubuntu, unix

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char buf[10];
  puts("gimme input:");
  fread(buf, 1, 10, stdin);
  printf("got %s", buf);
}
```

When I run this and open another terminal I try to write to stdin:

```
echo "ASDFASDFASDF" > /proc/{pid}/0
```

ASDFSADFSADF gets printed on the terminal that is running my C program, but fread still doesn't return until I type in the actual terminal. It also does not print any of the text that I wrote to /proc/{pid}/0

Is there something else I have to do to programatically input text to stdin?

Comment: No, you have to type the text in the same console you launched the program from, or, redirect the input from a file when you run the program. `echo` just send the test back to the console, not to the the program.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385771/writing-to-stdin-of-a-process

Comment: Why not just use a pipe or a heredoc?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this, vs. connecting your program's stdin to a FIFO and writing to that?

Comment: I was able to find a solution. See the post below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542495/writing-to-file-descriptor-0-stdin-only-affects-terminal-program-doesnt-read?noredirect=1#comment129870358_73542495

Answer (score 1):

If `stdin` is a terminal, then writing something to `stdin` will write to the terminal. Reading from the terminal will read whatever is typed into the terminal, not what's written to the terminal. This is just how terminals work.

If you want a program to read from something other than a terminal, you have to direct that to happen. Or, if you want to use a virtual terminal that you can put information into it and have it be read out, you have to direct that to happen.

Probably the simplest solution is to create a pipe with `mkpipe` and have the program read from the pipe rather than a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the `echo` command output-ing to the File Descriptor 0 you're just sending text. If you check the file descriptor using `ls -l` probably it is pointing to an device TTY or PTY/PTS. If you check the FD type using `lsof` it will be tty. It means you need to interact with this FD such as TTY.

Basically you need to simulate the input to get the expected behavior.

You can do this by calling the kernel tool `ioctl.tiocsti()`. I added a python code into the following similar question: [Writing to File descriptor 0 (STDIN) only affects terminal. Program doesn't read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542495/writing-to-file-descriptor-0-stdin-only-affects-terminal-program-doesnt-read)