# Writing to File descriptor 0 (STDIN) only affects terminal. Program doesn't read

Tags: python, linux, bash, file-descriptor

I'm studying file descriptors and I'm trying to simulate an input for FD 0 (STDIN). I'm testing in a linux environment. My intention is to write, via terminal, simulating an standard input to the code

Here is my python code:

```
import sys
from os import getpid

print(f'Hello world! Process: { getpid() }')


for line in sys.stdin:
    print(f'Echoing: {line}')
```

When I try to write into the associated FD 0 in another terminal:

```
echo "Test" >> /proc/<pid>/fd/0
```

It only prints in the terminal, the program never reads. I tried to add EOF, break line, heredoc, but I still not find a solution.

Is what I'm trying possible?

Comment: If you substitute a system utility like `cat` for your program, does that work?

Comment: The program under test's standard I/O file descriptors are probably connected to the process's controlling TTY (/dev/tty), so writing to that process's stdin file descriptor will write to that process's controlling TTY output (assuming the file descriptor is writable, which is likely because the file descriptors are set by `dup` or `dup2`).

Comment: @MarkRansom with cat I had the same behavior

Comment: Could you launch the program-under-test with its standard input redirected from a fifo (named pipe) or something? The testing program can write to the other end of the fifo.

Comment: That says then that the problem lies with the OS and not with Python.

Comment: The /proc/<pid>/fd/n directory entries are just symbolic links to named paths or to nameless entities that cannot be opened, such as pipe IDs or socket IDs. Opening the /proc/<pid>/fd/n entry will just (attempt to) open the same path, but that does not access the <pid>'s file descriptors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Ian Aboot's answers I could find some explanation here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385771/writing-to-stdin-of-a-process/385782

According to the answer of the post above:

> Accessing /proc/PID/fd/0 doesn't access file descriptor 0 of process PID, it accesses the file which PID has open on file descriptor 0. This is a subtle distinction, but it matters. A file descriptor is a connection that a process has to a file. Writing to a file descriptor writes to the file regardless of how the file has been opened.

and

> If /proc/PID/fd/0 is a terminal, then writing to it outputs the data on a terminal. A terminal file is bidirectional: writing to it outputs the data, i.e. the terminal displays the text; reading from a terminal inputs the data, i.e. the terminal transmits user input.

Basically I had to control the terminal process to get the input be forwarded into my process. Writing directly to the /dev/pts* didn't work.

Redirecting the input to a fifo, for example, worked as expected. Maybe there is a way to simulate something between the terminal process and the running program itself so I'll keep the research

**EDIT**

Finally I found a solution:

I was using `echo` command, so it was just writing text to the FD, instead we need to properly make the correct simulation as a device input, fake the input.

How to get it working? We need to simulate the input in the FD.

In the linux there is a way to simulate the terminal input, using the iocontrols (`ioctl`). One of the argument options is the TIOCSTI (Terminal input/output control - Simulate terminal input) that inserts a character in the input queue. Basically it simplifies the locking/input management of a given character.

We need the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability to be able to execute `tiocsti()` so I started a Python docker container with this linux capability turned on (see reference 4).

```py
#app/echo.py
import sys
from os import getpid

print(f'Hello world! Process: { getpid() }')


for line in sys.stdin:
    print(f'Echoing: {line}')
```

```py
#app/writer.py

from fcntl import ioctl
from termios import TIOCSTI
import sys


with open(f'/proc/{sys.argv[1]}/fd/0', 'w') as fd:
    for char in f'{sys.argv[2]}\n':
        ioctl(fd, TIOCSTI, char)
```

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  python:
    container_name: python_fd
    image: python:3.11-rc-bullseye
    cap_add:
    - CAP_SYS_ADMIN
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
          sleep 10000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/home/app
    working_dir: /home/app/
```

Terminal 1:

```bash
$ docker-compose up -d 
$ docker exec -it python_fd sh
# python echo.py
Hello world! Process: <pid>
```

Terminal 2:

```
$ docker exec -it python_fd sh
# python writer.py <process pid returned in the previous command> "Hello Lais"
```

Output of Terminal 1:

```
Hello Lais
Echoing: Hello Lais
```

References:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345572

https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages-dev/ioctl.2.en.html

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L2278